# Array out of index because of download delay

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I'm developing an app that downloads names and also images from Facebook, and display them into a CollectionView. The picture function is running just fine, but there's one little detail I'm stuck with the names. This is the code inside the CollectionView function for the text:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.facebook.com/" + newArray[indexPath.row])!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data {

            let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let websiteArray = webContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("pageTitle\">")
            let secondArray = websiteArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
            let title = secondArray[0]
            //----- serperated ---------
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {

                    if title == "Page Not Found" || title == "Pagina Niet Gevonden" {

                    } else {

                        stalkers.append(title)

                    }
            }

        }


    }
    task.resume()

    cell.label.text = stalkers[indexPath.row]
    return cell
```

The problem is when the app starts, it crashes with an error 'Array out of index'. I think this is because the array is empty when loading, and the downloading takes a while. I can't figure out how to make the label display each name AFTER it has been downloaded..

Any help is appreciated, really! Thanks!

Comment: try setting the labelText after download is complete. You can write callback handler after async download is complete

Comment: That is what completion blocks are for :) 
1. Download your data
2. When data finished appending to the array call `collectionView.reloadData` or similar (I'm not very experienced with collection views)

If collectionView has a datasource delegate-numberOfSomething-method you can simple set the count to your array.count, to prevent it from trying to load from the stalkers array.

Comment: Sorry, missed the part about the pictures working fine. If the names and pictures are related you could create a model User (or similar) which has a string and an UIImage as properties, and fill the CV with those. (or go with William Hu's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check this first:

```
if stalkers.count >= indexPath.row {
  cell.label.text = stalkers[indexPath.row]
}
```

And after download, assign the title:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {

                    if title == "Page Not Found" || title == "Pagina Niet Gevonden" {
                    } else {
                        stalkers.append(title)
                    }
    cell.label.text = stalkers[indexPath.row] //Add this line after download done.
            }
```

Comment: @Wiliam Hu please take a look at my code in my answer

Comment: I tried to use your code but for whatever reason it may be, the names only get loaded when I scroll down to the bottom, and when I scroll back the same name get's loaded so basically the name never gets displayed in the Collection View

Comment: dataTaskWithURL() is an async function, which means the code on it's block will run after data fetch. You have to set textLabel inside this async block, not outside. which is done in this answer.

Comment: May be you can upload your code. Or can you check if your set some cache stuff wrong due to the url get called whenever you scroll.